# Format returned table data in json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm fairly new to javascript. I retreive data from a sql server database that looks like this :

```
[Object { shortcode="0013A2004031AC9A", latest_measurement=1067, keyid="6801"}, 
 Object { shortcode="0013A2004031AC9A", latest_measurement=7, keyid="6802"}, 
 Object { shortcode="0013A2004031AC9A", latest_measurement=8598838, keyid="6803"}]
```

I want to format this in a json like this :

```
{mac : 0013A2004031AC9A, keys : {6801:1067, 6802:7, 6803:8598838}}
```

but I just don't get to that.

I have

```
var jsonDataPerMac = {};
```

I loop over the json object above and for every new mac I find I do :

```
 jsonDataPerMac[i]={"mac": device.shortcode, "keys":[]};
```

but how do I get to fill the keys?
Any hints would be appreciated.`enter code here`

```
var macs =  [];
var jsonDataPerMac = {};
var i = 0;            

$.ajax({
    url: "/bmmeasurements",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"unitid" : unitid},
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    initializeTable();

    $.each(data, function (index,device) {
     //add all distinct macs in an array, to use them as a column header
     if($.inArray(device.shortcode, macs) == -1) {
          macs.push(device.shortcode);
          jsonDataPerMac[i]={"mac": device.shortcode, "keys":[]};
          i++;

          //create a table cell for each possible key. id = 'mac-key'
          createTableGrid(device.shortcode);
          }

          //add the measurement data to the correct cell in the grid 
       $('#' + device.shortcode + '-' + device.keyid).html(device.latest_measurement);
          });
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposition. I would rather avoid using jQuery to perform such a simple operations. In this particular example, we use `forEach` and `for..in` loop.

```
//new output array
var newArray = [];

//we traverse the array received from AJAX call
array.forEach(function(el) {
    var added = false; // it's false by default

    // we check if the mac is already in newArray, if yes - just add the key
    for(var i in newArray) {
        if(newArray[i].mac == el.shortcode) {
           newArray[i].keys.push(el.keyid+":"+el.latest_measurement);
           added = true; // tells us whether the key has been added or not
        } 
    }

    // if key hasn't been added - create a new entry
    if(!added) {
        newArray.push({"mac": el.shortcode, "keys":[el.keyid+":"+el.latest_measurement]});
    }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

You can transform above code to a function and then, reuse it in your ajax onSuccess method. Remember to pass the array as an argument and to return newArray.

**JSFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/2d5Vq/2/

Comment: Thank you, this did perfectly what I was looking for. I much appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome :) You can always mark my answer as helpful, which will be a little reward to me.

Comment: After all it was not exactly what I wanted to do, but that was probably unclear in my example :                                      {mac : 0013A2004031AC9A, keys : {"6801":1067, "6802":7, "6803":8598838}} The 6801, 6082 and 6803 have to be identifiers like keys and mac. I want to address newArray.keys.6801 to be able to do calculations and comparisons between the different key values.

Comment: If you need any assistance with that, just leave a comment here and we will try to modify this code to make it fully working for you.

Comment: It would be really great if you could give me a hint on that one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2d5Vq/4/, hope now it works as expected. Please also note @Cindy that to access value at key which is integer, you should use keys[6802] instead of keys.6802 :)

Comment: That's it :) Perfect! Indeed I figured there still was a catch with thet numeric key. Now I can finally proceed my assignment :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the entries first...

```
var reducedData = {};
$.each(macs, function(index,macitem){
    if (reducedData.hasOwnProperty(macitem.shortcode)) {
        reducedData[macitem.shortcode].push(macitem.key);
    } else {
        reducedData[macitem.shortcode] = [ macitem.key ];
    }
});
```

And then map to your desired format inside an array...

```
var jsonDataPerMac = [],
    i = 0;
$.map(reducedData, function(keys,mac){
    jsonDataPerMac[i++] = {"mac": mac, "keys": keys};
    // your other code goes here
});
```

Also your usage of `jsonDataPerMac` suggests that you want it to be an array.